# Count elements (rows) in group of a data table

Tags: r

I have table (dt) which has several columns.

```
  X__1 First Name  Last Name Gender       Country Age       Date   Id
   1:    1      Dulce      Abril Female United States  32 15/10/2017 1562
   2:    2       Mara  Hashimoto Female Great Britain  25 16/08/2016 1582
   3:    3     Philip       Gent   Male        France  36 21/05/2015 2587
   4:    4   Kathleen     Hanner Female United States  25 15/10/2017 3549
   5:    5    Nereida    Magwood Female United States  58 16/08/2016 2468
```

I want to count the number of rows which has `Country = "France"` and `Age >32.`

I used the following command which gives me the result, but i need to count the number of rows in the result. What is the command to do it?

```
dt[Country == 'France' & Age > 32]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the function nrow()

```
nrow(dt[Country == 'France' & Age > 32])
```

Answer (score 1):

`nrow()` is simplest, but if you want to do it using `data.table` syntax:

```
dt[Country == 'France' & Age > 32, (.N)]
```